# How to find the value by find() and map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to obtain the value of `name` using the code below.
When `find(z => z.key.value === 123)` be added to the code ,there will be this error :

```
x.obj.array_1.find(...).find is not a function
```

What's wrong with this code :

```js
const data = [{
    "obj": {
      "array_1": [{
        "array_2": [{
          "array_3": [{
            "key": {
              "value": "123"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "name": "obj1"
  },
  {
    "obj": {
      "array_1": [{
        "array_2": [{
          "array_3": [{
            "key": {
              "value": "456"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "name": "obj2"
  },
  {
    "obj": {
      "array_1": [{
        "array_2": [{
          "array_3": [{
            "key": {
              "value": "789"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "name": "obj3"
  }
]
const name = data
  .filter(x =>
  x.obj.array_1.find(y => y.array_2).find(y => y.array_3).find(z =>   z.key.value === 123)
  ).map(x => x.name);
console.log(name)
```

Comment: `array_2.array_3` is not valid that could be `array_2[0].array_3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small fix here, this work provided that your real life data is also in this shape

After finding the propriate `array_1` element that have `array2[0]` which has non-nil `array_3`, you have to access that `array_3` to iterate and find the expected value

Edited (because `array_2` and `array_3` may have multiple elements): you have to extract all `array_3` element (using `flatMap` to flatten the nested array) and do the condition check from that extracted array

```js
const name = data
  .filter((x) => {
    const flattened_array_3 = x.obj.array_1.flatMap((array_1_el) =>
      array_1_el.array_2.flatMap((array_2_el) => array_2_el.array_3)
    )
    return flattened_array_3.find((array_3_el) => +array_3_el.key.value === 123)
  })
  .map((x) => x.name)
```

---

Full code

```js
const data = [
  {
    obj: {
      array_1: [
        {
          array_2: [
            {
              array_3: [
                {
                  key: {
                    value: "123",
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    name: "obj1",
  },
  {
    obj: {
      array_1: [
        {
          array_2: [
            {
              array_3: [
                {
                  key: {
                    value: "456",
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    name: "obj2",
  },
  {
    obj: {
      array_1: [
        {
          array_2: [
            {
              array_3: [
                {
                  key: {
                    value: "789",
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    name: "obj3",
  },
]
const name = data
  .filter((x) => {
    const flattened_array_3 = x.obj.array_1.flatMap((array_1_el) =>
      array_1_el.array_2.flatMap((array_2_el) => array_2_el.array_3)
    )
    return flattened_array_3.find((array_3_el) => +array_3_el.key.value === 123)
  })
  .map((x) => x.name)

console.log(name)
```

---

Reference: [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Thanks @hgb123 for your answer, It could be possible to do it without `[0]` for `array_2`? because `array_2` can have more than one object

Comment: I don not want to use `[0]` for non of them (`array_2,array_3`)

Comment: @Maya I updated the answer, so you have to extract all array_3 element (using flatMap to flatten the nested array) and do the condition check from that

Answer (score 0):

```
x.obj.array_1.find(y => y.array_2)
```

is undefined.

Try to split your code

Answer (score 0):

In order to work on this structure, I advise you to change the way you represent data.
It seems like some kind of output of tokenization. There have to bee tools to extract information from the path for example XPath, etc.
On the other hand below code should work for your case

The key point is using `flatMap` to rest inner arrays to upper  one

```js
const data = [{
    "obj": {
      "array_1": [{
        "array_2": [{
          "array_3": [{
            "key": {
              "value": "123"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "name": "obj1"
  },
  {
    "obj": {
      "array_1": [{
        "array_2": [{
          "array_3": [{
            "key": {
              "value": "456"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "name": "obj2"
  },
  {
    "obj": {
      "array_1": [{
        "array_2": [{
          "array_3": [{
            "key": {
              "value": "789"
            }
          }]
        }]
      }]
    },
    "name": "obj3"
  }
]


var obj = data.find(x=> x.obj.array_1.flatMap(x=>x.array_2).flatMap(x=>x.array_3)[0].key.value==789)
console.log(obj.name)
```